# Is it possible to create a website in firebase multi site hosting through the cli?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

We are looking into using firebase for hosting our websites, but we can't figure out a way to create multiple websites in a single project without going to the interface and doing it manually. Is it possible to use `firebase-tools` or a different gce service for this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there is no way to create a new sub-site through the Firebase CLI at the moment. You can deploy to multiple sites through the CLI, but you will have to set each site up through the Firebase (web) console.

Comment: Yes, this was my conclusion as well. Do you think it might be possible to ask them directly if this is something they plan on implementing?

Comment: If you'd like to request this feature, I suggest to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).